# auto start web app at tomcat deployment time

Tags: apache, tomcat, servlets, web.xml

I have a JSP/Servelt webapp running on apache tomcat. I'm deploying this webapp in a external tomcat server using the .WAR file.

How can I configure it as, when the .WAR file is deployed the webapp is also started automatically. (what are the changes that I have to do in web.xml file or context.xml or any other changes)

How can I configure, ones web app is started it runs continuously?

Comment: How you deploying your war file?

Comment: I'm only uploading the .WAR file to the live server in a given interface. Deployment happen inside the live server automatically after I upload

Answer (score 0):

Automate your web app(WAR) deployment through external script ( like shell script) and once your deployment is complete run startup script of tomcat.

This is more safer way to do than thinking of modifying your deployment descriptors.

Comment: @ria.skumar- I don't have permission for file access on the live server. So I can't run scripts on live server. Please tell me how to modify deployment descriptors if you know it. Thanks